# Suppose $\sum a_n c^n$ diverges for some real number c. Then $\sum a_n x^n $ diverges for all x such that |x| > |c|.

Tags: calculus

Suppose $\sum a_n c^n$ diverges for some real number c. Then $\sum a_n x^n $ diverges for all x such that |x| > |c|.

how can I prove it by using contradiction and using this theorem Suppose $\sum a_n c^n$ converges for some nonzero real number c. Then $\sum a_n x^n $ converges absolutely for all x such that |x| < |c|.

Comment: You're aware that a direct implication ($P$ implies $Q$) and its contrapositive (not-$Q$ implies not-$P$) are logically equivalent...?

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose $\sum a_n c^n$ diverges for some real number $c$. Then $\sum a_n x^n $ ***diverges*** for all x such that $|x| > |c|$.

Suppose this is not true, so suppose you can find a number $d$ such that $|d| > |c|$ and $\sum a_n d^n $ ***converges***. Now use (I've replaced $c$ by $d$ to avoid confusion, apply it to the $d$ from above):

> Suppose $\sum a_n d^n$ converges for some nonzero real number $d$. Then $\sum a_n x^n $ converges absolutely for all x such that $|x| < |d|$.

What does it say about $x=c$, the  initial $c$...?